# Inverse image of an open interval

Tags: general-topology

For a topological space $X$, there is a function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
Suppose that both $A = \{ x \in X : f(x) \ge r\}$ and $B = \{ x \in X : f(x) \le r\}$ are closed for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, one should show that the inverse image of an open interval is again open (using the hint that it's the compliment of a closed set).

So, I understand that I should show that $ f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ maps to an open set, by showing that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = X \setminus D $, where $D$ is some closed set.

However, using the sets $A, B$ provided, I would conclude that $\forall x \in X, x \in A \cup B$. As this is the union of two closed sets, it must be closed two; and therefore, $X$ must be closed too.

Therefore, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ would map to a closed set, whereas one should show that it maps to an open set.

What's wrong with my line of reasoning? What else could be meant with $X \setminus D$?

Thanks!

Comment: If $X$ is any topological space whatsoever, $X$ is both an open and a closed set in $X$.

Comment: Then what's the point of showing what $f^{-1}$ maps to, if it's known a priori that $X$ is open?

Comment: Where does the $R^n$ come from? Is the function from $R^n$ to $R$?

Comment: @bonifaz: Although you did not say so, presumably you’re supposed to be showing that $f$ is continuous. This requires you to show that $f^{-1}[(a,b)]$ is open in $X$ for every open interval $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R$. That $f^{-1}[\Bbb R]$ is open is a given.

Comment: @StefanH, that was by mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for your clarification. That brought me on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should show that $f^{-1}[(a,b)]$ is open in $X$ for every open interval $(a,b)$.

$$ f^{-1}[(a,b)] = \{ x \in X : a < f(x) < b\} = \{ x \in X : a < f(x)\} \cap \{ x \in X : f(x) < b\}$$

$$f^{-1}[(a,b)] = X \setminus ( \{x \in X : a \ge f(x)\} \cup \{ x \in X : f(x) \ge b\})$$

As both $\{x \in X : a \ge f(x)\}$ and $\{ x \in X : f(x) \ge b\}$ are known to be closed, their union is closed too, and therefore the compliment $f^{-1}[(a,b)]$ is open.